# I cant manage to put my javascript function to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im creating accounts on a api and the password needs those restrictions.The handleRegist() is connecting to the api but the passwords i use always goes through that if cycle.I am using a function to check the password strength for a login the password must contain at least 1 special character 1 uppercase letter and it must be longer than 8 characters.
I have this code so far:

```
function passwordChecker(password){
        var strongPassword = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$/;
             if (password.value.match(strongPassword)) {
                 console.log("Good Password");
                 handleRegist();
        }else
        console.log("Try Again!\nnot strong enough");
    }
```

NOTE: the strongPassword variable i found it on the internet and i am not sure if the restriction works like that.

Comment: In what way can't you get it to work? Is it logging anything? This question needs more detail.

Comment: Im creating accounts on a api and the password needs those restrictions.The handleRegist() is connecting to the api but the password i use always goes through that if cycle

Comment: That's fine but you need to tell us _how_ it isn't working. What debugging have you done? What is your example input, and your expected output? Did you mean to `return` something from the function?

Comment: i wanted to return those console logs to see if it was getting trough but it isnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to fire the function you need to call it from somewhere, naturally, you would like to call it inside the onchange event inside the input component.

```
 <input
    type="text"
    onChange={(e) => passwordChecker({ value: e.target.value })}
  />
```

Here is a working codesandbox example:
[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-snow-fml4ko?file=/src/App.js)
(open the console from the bottom of the page to see the result while typing inside the input)

Notice: im passing the value inside an object `{value: e.target.value}`, im doing it because inside your function you are checking `password.value.match(strongPassword)`, it expect to get `password.value`, therefore i needed to add the value inside an object and pass it to the function.

i recommend to handle the value and store it in a state with useState and pass the state as value to the input.